# How can I set the data-amount attribute of this eway script dynamically with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, payment-gateway

How can I change the data-amount of the following script dynamically with js/jquery ?

```
     <script src="https://secure.ewaypayments.com/scripts/eCrypt.js"
           class="eway-paynow-button"               
           data-publicapikey="epk-4CE77D3C-FEE1-4FA5-98C9-7B67D22198EC"
           data-amount="0"
           data-currency="AUD" >
        </script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('script.eway-paynow-button').attr('data-amount', '10');
```

Will set the value to 10 using jQuery. The script that runs this command must either come after the paynow script, or otherwise run in a callback function, such as jQuery's document.ready function.

I think the eway script may also have to be in the body of the document rather than the head.

Comment: Nice work! The script does need to be in the body since the button will display wherever the script is. Also bear in mind that "10" will be 10 cents!